# Does floating point mantissa store bits right to left

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

I've just checked how the number **3** is stored and it's stored like this:

```
0 10000000000 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

whereas I expected it to be stored like this:

```
0 10000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

How are bits laid out in mantissa under IEEE-754? Why is `1` on the left and not on the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the following is for normal values. The rules for denormals, infinites or NaNs are different, but not relevant for the value `3`.

The mantissa (a.k.a. significand) is stored as `1.` plus a fraction. The 1 is "always" there, so it is not stored. The fraction is stored as top bit `0.5 (2^-1)`, next bit `0.25 (2^-2)`, etc.

`3` is stored as 1.5 * 2<sup>1</sup>. The `1.` is not stored, so only the `0.5` bit is stored, which is what you see. All following (lower order) bits are `0`. The exponent is `0x400`, which is `1` + the bias of `1023` (`0x3FF`), or binary: `100 0000 0000`. The sign bit is `0` (for not-negative).

How this is stored physically, depends on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your system. Little-endian systems store the low byte first (the last `0x00`), big-endian systems store the top byte first (the sign bit and the top bits of the exponent, in this case, the top `0x40`).

The textual representation in bits is independent of that. The sign bit is always the top bit, always displayed on the left, the exponent the bits below that and below that the mantissa.

Let's take a look at the bits in the textual representation:

```
0 10000000000 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Let's reformat them:

```
0100 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

or in hex digits:

```
   4    0    0    8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

This is stored as a single 64 bit value, in hex:

```
0x4008000000000000
```

That 64 bit ***value*** is independent of endianness (just like the integer **value** decimal `12345` is independent of endianness, it is and remains the number `12345`, no matter how you store it). But if we start ***storing*** the value, the order of the bytes becomes important.

In big-endian, this is stored as the following 8 consecutive bytes:

```
0x40 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

In little-endian, this is stored as the following 8 consecutive bytes:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x40
```

Comment: thanks, I know it all. My question is whether fraction is stored left to right. Based on your sentence _The fraction is stored as top bit 0.5 (2^-1), next bit 0.25 (2^-2), etc._ - I conclude that it does, correct?

Comment: and how is bias 127? it's supposed to be 1023 for 11 bits

Comment: It is stored top to bottom. How this is stored in bytes depends on the endianness of your system. In little-endian, it is stored with the lowest byte first, in big-endian it is stored with the top byte first (the one containing the sign and the top of the exponent)

Comment: thanks, though it's still unclear. Let's talk about textual representation first. If we have the number 1.1101, where is top bit here? Is this number in textual representation going to be represented as 110100000... or ...0000011101?

Comment: Also, as I understand from [this article](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html), little and big endianess only related to the position of entire bytes, not individual bits, correct? So as I understand the textual representation of 64bits are split by bytes, so the mantissa will be split between 3rd and 4th byte.

Comment: The top bit is the leftmost bit. Your value, 3, is as you displayed. The top bit is the sign bit, then follow 11 bits for the exponent and 52 bits for the mantissa. The bit representing 1 for the mantissa is not stored, so you don't see it. So the leftmost bit of the *stored mantissa* is the bit for 2^-1, then follows the bit for 2^-2, etc. This is like decimal numbers: the top digit (the one with the highest power of 10) is the leftmost one.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, I've got it. I've checked and this order `01000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` is correct in big endianess, while in little endianess it looks like this `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 01000000`. So _textual representation_ seems to match big endianess represenation in memory

Comment: Yes, more or less that's right. Note that `0x40` is the same as binary `01000000`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaboration! Best of luck